# Сопоставление шаблонов с несколькими объектами OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Как найти похожие объекты на картинке код нашел, как найти координаты этих объектов на картинке не могу найти.
Можно найти координаты когда ищем 1 объект методом:

```
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)  # функция для определения координат
a, b = max_loc
```

Код адаптировал с https://pythonpip.ru/opencv/sopostavlenie-s-shablonom-v-opencv
Все работает:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Загружаем картинку на которой ищем
img_rgb = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\gundr\Desktop\Sk\Screenshot_13.png')  # вписать ваш путь
# преобразовываем её
img_rgb = np.array(img_rgb)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# загружаем картинку которую ищем
template = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\gundr\Desktop\Sk\coin1.png')

# высота ширана искомого объекта
w, h = template.shape[:-1]
# стравниваем
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

# Находим контуры
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt,(pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h),(0,255,255), 2)

while True:
        cv2.imshow('Detected', img_rgb)
        key_press = cv2.waitKey(30)
        if key_press == ord('q'):
            cl_pr = True
            break

# ВОПРОС: КАК НАЙТИ КООРДИНАТЫ НАЙДЕННЫХ ОБЪЕКТОВ?
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как найти координаты найденных объектов на картинке!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: max_loc это координата левого верхнего угла внутри img_gray с которого начинается совпадение img_gray и template, но это только один объект, остальные сложнее

Comment: чтобы найти остальные, надо найти локальные максимумы, это точки пересечения 0 второй производной. Можно конечно по уровню 0.8 всё отбросить (занулить), но внутри оставшего как-то надо будет искать

Comment: выведите результат, через `applyColorMap( ..., cv.COLORMAP_MAGMA)` чтобы визуально видеть точки совпадения, полезно для понимания

Comment: Зачем вы переводите картинку в HSV  и называете это серым?  А затем ищете на ней BRG  образец? cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats  выдает центроиды, используйте ее.

Answer (score -1):

Нашел ответ, в этой теме

```
import cv2
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression # pip install imutils

# Load the image and template
image = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
template = cv2.imread(template_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Perform template matching 
result = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

# Filter results to only good ones
threshold = 0.90 # Larger values have less, but better matches.
(yCoords, xCoords) = np.where(result >= threshold)

# Perform non-maximum suppression.
template_h, template_w = template.shape[:2]
rects = []
for (x, y) in zip(xCoords, yCoords):
  rects.append((x, y, x + template_w, y + template_h))
pick = non_max_suppression(np.array(rects))

# Optional: Visualize the results
for (startX, startY, endX, endY) in pick:
  cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),(0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('Results', image)
```